# Databricks connect & PyCharm & remote SSH connection

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, databricks-connect

Hey StackOverflowers!

I run into a problem.

I have set up PyCharm to be connected with an (azure) VM through SSH connection.

1. So first i make the configuration for the ssh connection
   [image]
2. I set up the mappings
3. I create a conda enviroment by spining up a terminal in the vm and then I download and connect to databricks-connect. I test it on the terminal and it works fine.
4. I set up the console on the pycharm configurations
   [image]

But when I try to run the spark session (spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()), databricks-connect searches for the .databricks-connect file in the wrong folder and gives me the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Config file /root/.databricks-connect not found. Please run` databricks-connect configure `to accept the end user license agreement and configure Databricks Connect. A copy of the EULA is provided below: Copyright (2018) Databricks, Inc.`

and the full error + some warnings.

```
20/07/10 17:23:05 WARN Utils: Your hostname, george resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.0.0.4 instead (on interface eth0)
20/07/10 17:23:05 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
20/07/10 17:23:05 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-23fe18298795>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/azureuser/code/model/check_vm.py')
  File "/home/azureuser/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/home/azureuser/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/azureuser/code/model/check_vm.py", line 13, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "/anaconda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 185, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 373, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/anaconda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 137, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 199, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 312, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1525, in __call__
    answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:250)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Config file /root/.databricks-connect not found. Please run `databricks-connect configure` to accept the end user license agreement and configure Databricks Connect. A copy of the EULA is provided below: Copyright (2018) Databricks, Inc.
This library (the "Software") may not be used except in connection with the Licensee's use of the Databricks Platform Services pursuant to an Agreement (defined below) between Licensee (defined below) and Databricks, Inc. ("Databricks"). This Software shall be deemed part of the “Subscription Services” under the Agreement, or if the Agreement does not define Subscription Services, then the term in such Agreement that refers to the applicable Databricks Platform Services (as defined below) shall be substituted herein for “Subscription Services.”  Licensee's use of the Software must comply at all times with any restrictions applicable to the Subscription Services, generally, and must be used in accordance with any applicable documentation. If you have not agreed to an Agreement or otherwise do not agree to these terms, you may not use the Software.  This license terminates automatically upon the termination of the Agreement or Licensee's breach of these terms.
Agreement: the agreement between Databricks and Licensee governing the use of the Databricks Platform Services, which shall be, with respect to Databricks, the Databricks Terms of Service located at www.databricks.com/termsofservice, and with respect to Databricks Community Edition, the Community Edition Terms of Service located at www.databricks.com/ce-termsofuse, in each case unless Licensee has entered into a separate written agreement with Databricks governing the use of the applicable Databricks Platform Services. Databricks Platform Services: the Databricks services or the Databricks Community Edition services, according to where the Software is used.
Licensee: the user of the Software, or, if the Software is being used on behalf of a company, the company.
To accept this agreement and start using Databricks Connect, run `databricks-connect configure` in a shell.
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksConnectConf$.checkEula(DatabricksConnectConf.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.<init>(SparkContext.scala:2679)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.<clinit>(SparkContext.scala)
    ... 13 more
```

However, I do not have access rights to that folder so I can not drop there the databricks connect file.

What is also strange is that if I run in  : Pycharm -> ssh terminal -> activate conda env -> python the following

Is it a way to either:

```
1. Point out to java where the databricks-connect file is

2. Configure databricks-connect in another way throughout the script or enviromental variables inside pycharm

3. Other way? 

or do I miss something?
```

Comment: I'm guessing it is looking in the `/root/` directory because you're running as root.  Have you tried running the command as a regular user?  Does it look in the same directory?  Are you able to install `databricks-connect` in a virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect#:%7E:text=Azure%20Databricks%20notebook.-,Overview,run%20the%20DataFrame%20command%20spark.) seems to be the official tutorial for how to do what you want (ie databricks connect).

Most likely, you have the wrong version of the .databricks-connect file.

You need to use Java 8 not 11, Databricks Runtime 5.5 LTS or Databricks Runtime 6.1-6.6, and your python edition should be the same on both ends.

Here are the steps they give:

```
conda create --name dbconnect python=3.5
pip uninstall pyspark
pip install -U databricks-connect==5.5.*  # or 6.*.* to match your cluster version. 6.1-6.6 are supported
```

Then you need the url, token, cluster id, org id and port. Finally run this command on the terminal:

```
databricks-connect configure
databricks-connect test
```

There's more to do after that but that should hopefully work. Keep in mind that you need to make sure all of the programs you use are compatible. After you have all of the setup complete then try setting up the ide (pycharm) to work.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial and works all fine in the local machine. It also works fine when I do it in the VM in a terminal. The problem arises when I want to use Pycharm & ssh connection

Comment: Can you try it with another ide (like spyder) and see if the error repeats itself?

Comment: I tried for VScode and it works fine. So it has to be something with the configuration in Pycharm

Comment: Then most likely you're correct and there's something up with your Pycharm config, or Pycharm still has some bugs when connecting with databricks. Maybe you should reach out to JetBrains about it?

Answer (score 1):

From the error I see you need to accept the Terms and conditions by databricks, secondly follow these instruction for pycharm IDE [databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#id4)

- **CLI**

  Run

  ```
  databricks-connect configure
  ```

  The license displays:

  > Copy to clipboardCopy Copyright (2018) Databricks, Inc.
  >
  > This library (the "Software") may not be used except in connection
  > with the Licensee's use of the Databricks Platform Services pursuant
  > to an Agreement   ...

  Accept the license and supply configuration values.

  ```
  Do you accept the above agreement? [y/N] y
  ```

  > Set new config values (leave input empty to accept default):
  > Databricks Host [no current value, must start with https://]:
  >  Databricks Token [no current value]:
  >  Cluster ID (e.g., 0921-001415-jelly628) [no current
  > value]:  Org ID (Azure-only, see ?o=orgId in URL) [0]:
  >  Port [15001]:
- The Databricks Connect configuration script automatically adds the
  package to your project configuration.

  Python 3 clusters Go to Run > Edit Configurations.

  Add **PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3** as an environment variable.

  Python 3 cluster configuration

Comment: thanks Yash for your answer. Unfortunately, I have followed those steps and while it works fine in the terminal it does not work through PyCharm

Comment: I am guessing some config files might be interfering can you uninstall it with all the config removed and reinstall it to get back the defaults and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

At the end did you manage to set-up a remote Pycharm ssh interpreter on Databricks. I'm currently assessing if Databricks could do the job for a project I'm working on.

As far as I understood `databricks-connect` is only helpful to launch Spark jobs on the remote machine, while the rest of your non-spark code is executed locally ...